# Open with Wine/Photoshop not working properly

Tags: wine, photoshop

I am running Photoshop CS2 under Ubuntu 10.10 with Wine 1.3.23. I would like to be able to associate various file types with Photoshop. I'd previously used this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
QUICKPARLOCATION="c:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Photoshop CS2\\Photoshop.exe"
PARAM=`winepath -w "$*"`
wine "$QUICKPARLOCATION" "$PARAM"
exit 0
```

If I make this script be the customer command that's tied to "Open With," Photoshop launches, but doesn't appear to be properly passing the file name, so that file doesn't open. I'd had this working previously under earlier versions of Ubuntu and wine.

P.S. please no commentary on using GIMP or other Photoshop alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom command should be possible in one string without needing a script.

The following custom command will launch photoshop via wine:

```
wine "c:\\program files\\adobe\\adobe photoshop cs2\\photoshop.exe" \"z:%f\"
```

The key part is the last part `\"z:%f\`

- `%f` passes the filename selected.
- Prefixing `z:` does the same as `winepath -w` for a file which you double-click.

Comment: I initially tried your suggestion and it didn't work. I then took a look at my wine config and see that I'd previously mapped the "Z" drive to something else. Once I removed the mapping, all was good... this has been bugging me for a while, so thanks very much for your input.